# How can I insert a new database record in the middle of an existing table?

Tags: sql

I want to insert a **new highlighted row** in my table, but there is already some data present before. What should I do?

please find the picture below;

[image]

I would like to have SQL Statements in Rails.

Comment: Sort your output: `SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY Date`

Comment: You don't decide where a row is inserted, but you can decide the returned order when SELECT. Do ORDER BY Date.

Comment: SQL tables don't have any inherent order. There's no such thing as inserting in a specific place.

Comment: you can't control where to insert the record, but you can sort the result of `SELECT` also consider adding a column `display_order` with `int` dataType, set the value on insert, and sort the result `order by display_order ASC/DESC`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But i am using rails application and how i change my  migration files in order to get the desired results. Waiting for your reply....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the below approach;

```
User.find(previous id value).update_column(:id, new id value)
```

For example, id value of 1st row is 1 and id value of third row is 2 and to place the highlighted row whose id value is 3 in between.
At first we will change the id value = 2 to 4 and consequently change the id value = 3 to 2 hence the result.Hope everything is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Tables in SQL don't have a defined order (they might have, depending on the concrete implementation, but you cannot count on it).

If you require a certain ordering, you must order your result set when selecting.

Therefore, I can see two possibilities:

1. Update every id above the 'missing' row, and insert your new row using the newly 'freed' id. This will probably break a lot of other stuff (references to your ids will require updating as well).
2. Introduce a new column which defines the ordering. This way, ordering can be independent of the row's id.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed the first approach and got it working.